# Form visible in Design View, but blank in Form View

Tags: forms, ms-access-2007

My form is showing up in design, but not form view.  There are 700+ records.

In `Design View` -> `Data`, the `Record Source` is:

```
SELECT act.* FROM act;
```

This query shows all records in Query view.

There are no filters, and `Allow Form View` is set to Yes.

What is causing my form not to show?

EDIT: I'm noticing that the form is extremely wide.  There isn't a width setting, but in Design view with window maximized I have to scroll way over to see the right edge.  Would this have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto_title_0 was set to 21" wide.  Resizing that to the actual form width solved the problem.

Answer (score 5):

This link might help you. I remember having this issue and it was because of a read-only query.

[Why does my form go completely blank?](http://allenbrowne.com/casu-20.html)

Here is an excerpt that lists the main conditions why this could happen:

```
Condition (a) can be triggered in several ways. Examples:

 - The form's Data Entry property is set to Yes. (This means the form shows no existing records, i.e. it is for entering new ones only.)
 - The form has a Filter applied (or is opened with a WhereCondition) that yields no records.
 - The form is based on a query where the criteria yield no records.
 - The form is based on a table that has no records.

Condition (b) can be also be triggered by several things:
 - The form's Allow Additions property is set to No.
 - The form's Recordset Type property is set to something other than Dynaset.
 - The form is based on a read-only query. (If you cannot add a record directly to your query, see Why is my query read-only?)
```

Comment: I just noticed you found the answer to your problem but will leave my answer for future reference.

Comment: This comment saved me after many hours of debugging. I was working with a SQL-Server linked table that lacked a primary key, so it both lacked records and records could not be added (read only query) adding a primary key to the SQL Server table and refreshing the link fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

On Design View of the Form click on "Details" which is just below the ruler and make sure that Visible is set to Yes on the Property Sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Try this step.

1. Click to select Form.
2. Click on Auto Resize.
3. Change value to Yes.

[Look into this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZ3Ma.png)

Answer (score 0):

I also had the issue with a Form I used to input the strings for a query. The problem was that there were no records to answer query as I had changed it to an "Select Distinct" query to get rid of duplicate answers, but it also eliminated new record sets. Deleting the "Distinct" in my SQL solved the problem. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For me - the Form.Data Entry property was set to Yes.
Changing it to No shows the form again.

Answer (score 0):

As for my case, I had open two forms.

Form B is link to Form A.
When Form B is opened, Form A is blank because it does not allow for data to be added.

When I close Form B and re-open (or refresh) Form A, the form fields appear.

Answer (score 0):

Hope someone finds this helpful.. I faced this problem and solved by changing Pop On  property (under the other tab) to No, and also changing the border style to "Dialog" in design view mode.

Answer (score 0):

I **deleted relationship** (which was created during form creation) then the form data are displaying again.

Comment: Please add the code example to make this a more complete Answer.

Answer (score -1):

I also had this problem which wasted lots of time, but I was able to fix it.

The reason for me was that my target table was empty and I had primary keys set on it and had my controls in my form related to those fields. 
So, Access was unable to show blank primary keys and was not displaying the form at all.

If you fill up your target table with some data, save and close the form and open it again the controls will be displayed.