# Blank forms for certain users

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-forms

I created an MS Access Database with around 1000 entries. This database has forms that can change or add new entries, some forms only allow users to view data.

I released this database, however a small amount of users can't seem to see anything on some forms (coincidentally these seem to be the forms where data entries can be entered or changed). They can see everything on the forms where data entries are read-only.

All users have the same version of the database, so I can't seem to find out why it just doesn't work for some people. Another similar question; [Form visible in Design View, but blank in Form View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16548650/form-visible-in-design-view-but-blank-in-form-view) couldn't help me out either.

Does anyone know why this may happen?

Edit: I have asked the users for which this error occurs, to update all VBA packages, this hasn't worked though.

Comment: How you are managing user permission to view only or add/edit?

Comment: @Harun24HR I have the 'Data Entry' property switched on for forms that require input, view-only forms have this property switched off

Comment: Is it a split database? Do all users have the same Office version?

Comment: @Andre Yes, it's a split database. The users all have the latest Office version. The backend is located on a Server that everyone has access to, the frontend is copied from the server to a local location

Comment: Double-check that every user has **write** access to the backend. Have them open the folder, try to create a file, try to directly open the backend.

Comment: Double checked that, however still I can't seem to find the error. Opening the file on their computer works without any problem.

Comment: @Andre is right. For some reason, these users have not been granted _write and delete_ access to the backend file or (more likely) the folder holding this. Discuss this with your server administrator.

Comment: @Andre thanks for your answer! The server admin checked again, the affected users did apparently not have **write** access to the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution, as suspected:

The affected users did not have write access to the backend.

I'm actually a little surprised that Access is so clever (?) to show edit forms blank in this case. :)